# Need to replace big content inside a Javascript library

Tags: javascript, notepad

I need to update and existing Javascript library that is divided between around 200 subdocuments. My point, is that i cant replace entire paragraphs in either notepad or word. Is there a word processor that can facilitate my job? Excuse my english as i am Greek.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: How much you achieved?

Comment: So you want to find and replace large blocks of code? If yes, try [sublime](https://www.sublimetext.com/) It can find and replace within a directory.

Comment: What do you mean with "libary divided between 200 subdocuments"? One library divided into multiple files? And what do you mean with "paragraphs"? Multiple lines/block of code in this library? What do you want to replace these "paragraphs" with?